# How do I flatten an iterator of Result<Vec<T>,E> to return an iterator of Result<T,E> in rust?

Tags: rust, error-handling, functional-programming

This is my test case; it doesn't compile because of incompatible match arms.  How should I fix that, or what's a better way to get a flattened iterator here?

```
fn main() {
    let v1: Vec<Result<Vec<u32>, &str>> = vec![ Ok(vec![1,2,3]), Ok(vec![4,5,6,9]), Err("failed"), ];

    let iter1 = v1.iter();

    let flattened_iter1 = iter1.map(|x| match x {
        Ok(v) => v.iter().map(|v| Ok(v)),
        Err(e) => once(Err(e)),
    }).flatten();

    for r in flattened_iter1 {
        match r {
            Ok(i) => println!("{}", i),
            Err(i) => { println!("Error"); break },
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While in the general case I would use the `either` crate, in this specific case `itertools` has gotten you covered with [`flatten_ok()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.flatten_ok):

```rust
use itertools::Itertools;

let flattened_iter1 = iter1.map(Result::as_ref).flatten_ok();
```

Comment: Indeed, [flatten_ok()](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.flatten_ok) was exactly what I was looking for, have now converted to that, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

One option is to use the [`either` crate](https://docs.rs/either/latest/either/index.html), which provides the `Either<L, R>` enum.  An `Either<L, R>` can be either `Either::Left(L)` or `Either::Right(R)`, and `Either<L, R>` implements `Iterator` itself when both `L` and `R` implement `Iterator` with the same `Iterator::Item` type.

This gives you similar flexibility to a boxed trait object but without the overhead of heap allocation.  There is still dynamic dispatch, but handled internally by `Either` as a conditional instead of a function pointer call.

```
use std::iter::once;
use either::Either;

fn main() {
    let v1: Vec<Result<Vec<u32>, &str>> = vec![ Ok(vec![1,2,3]), Ok(vec![4,5,6,9]), Err("failed"), ];

    let iter1 = v1.iter();

    let flattened_iter1 = iter1.map(|x| match x {
        Ok(v) => Either::Left(v.iter().map(|v| Ok(v))),
        Err(e) => Either::Right(once(Err(e))),
    }).flatten();

    for r in flattened_iter1 {
        match r {
            Ok(i) => println!("{}", i),
            Err(i) => { println!("Error"); break },
        }
    }
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a2e0b5a2f1a8759fcd7a38f7041fcaa8))

Answer (score 2):

This won't work because `map` and `once` produce two different types. What you would like would be a way of telling to Rust you don't really care that they are different types, the only thing you care is that they are both iterators. To do so, you could explicitly cast them as trait objects `once(Err(e)) as dyn Iterator<Item=Result<u32, &str>>`, but that wouldn't work because then Rust couldn't know their size at compile time. To make it work, you need to allocate them on the heap rather than on the stack, leading to

```rust
use std::iter::once;

fn main() {
    let v1 = vec![ Ok(vec![1,2,3]), Ok(vec![4,5,6,9]), Err("failed"), ];

    let flattened_iter1 = v1
        .iter()
        .map(|x| match x {
            Ok(v) => Box::new(v.iter().map(|v| Ok(v))) as Box<dyn Iterator<Item=_>>,
            Err(e) => Box::new(once(Err(e))) as Box<dyn Iterator<Item=_>>,
        })
        .flatten();

    for r in flattened_iter1 {
        match r {
            Ok(i) => println!("{}", i),
            Err(i) => { println!("Error"); break },
        }
    }
}
```

You can try this [on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6535a6926cccd8ce459067d3ca21a149).

There are a few things to note with this approach:

- `Box`ing stuff is not free, as it results in actual allocate, but it's also not super expensive. Compared to the solution where you just collect everything into a single `Vec` to iterate on that, this is probably cheaper;
- Similarly, working with trait objects is not free (because they have to bring their own vtable and everything), but it's also not very expensive.
- I didn't have to specify the actual iterator `Item` because Rust was able to figure it out on its own.

Comment: I ended up using the Either approach, but this would also have done the job, and your comments are instructive.

Comment: @AlexKing TBH, I think indeed the `Either` approach is more convenient, if it applies (apart from being slightly more efficient).